# Do I need to start multiple server-side workers for just a handful of ZeroMQ clients?

Tags: erlang, zeromq, chumak

I am using Chumak in erlang, opening a **`ROUTER`** socket.

I have a handful (4 or so) clients that use the Python zmq library to send **`REQ`** requests to this server.

Things work fine most of the time, but sometimes a client will have disconnect issues (reconnecting automatically is in the client code, and it works).  I've found that when an error occurs in one client connection, it seems to move on to others as well, and I get a lot of
`** {{noproc,{gen_server,call,[<0.31596.16>,incomming_queue_out]}},`
on the server.

On the server side, I'm just opening one chumak socket and looping:

```
{ok, Sock} = chumak:socket( router ),
{ok, _}    = chumak:bind( Sock, tcp, "0.0.0.0", ?PORT ),
spawn_link( fun() -> loop( Sock ) end ),
...

loop( CmdSock ) ->
    {ok, [Identity, <<>>, Data]} = chumak:recv_multipart( Sock ),
    ...
```

The ZeroMQ docs seem to imply that one listening socket is enough unless I have many clients.
Do I misunderstand them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, there is no need to increase number of `Socket` instances

Abstractions are great to reduce a need to understand all the details under the hood for a typical user. That ease of life stops whenever such user has to go into performance tuning or debugging incidents.

Let's step in this way:
- unless some mastodon beast sized data payloads are to get moved through, there is quite enough to have a single `ROUTER`-AccessPoint into a **`Socket`**-instance, for say tens, hundreds, thousands of `REQ`-AccessPoints on the client side(s).
- yet, such numbers will increase the performance envelope requirements for the `ROUTER`-side **`Context`**-instance, so as to remain capable of handling all the Scalable Formal Communication Archetype ( pre-scribed ) handling, so as to all happen in due time and fair fashion.

This means, one can soon realise benefits from spawning `Context`-instances with more than its initial default solo-thread + in all my high-performance setups I advocate for using **`zmq.AFFINITY`** mappings, so as to squeeze indeed a max performance on highest-priority `Socket`-instances, whereas leaving non-critical resources sharing a common sub-set of the `Context`-instance's IO-thread-pool.

---

Next comes **RAM**
Yes, the toys occupy memory.
Check all the `.{RCV|SND}BUF`, `.MAXMSGSIZE`, `.{SND|RCV}HWM`, `.BACKLOG`, `.CONFLATE`

---

Next comes **LINK-MANAGEMENT**

Do not hesitate to optimise `.IMMEDIATE`, `.{RCV|SND}BUF`, `.RECONNECT_IVL`, `.RECONNECT_IVL_MAX`, `.TCP_KEEPALIVE`, `.TCP_KEEPALIVE_CNT`, `.TCP_KEEPALIVE_INTVL`, `.TCP_KEEPALIVE_IDLE`

Always set `.LINGER` right upon instantiations, as drop-outs cease to be lethal.

---

Next may come a few defensive and performance helper tools:

`.PROBE_ROUTER`, `.TCP_ACCEPT_FILTER`, `.TOS`, `.HANDSHAKE_IVL`

---

### Next step?

If no memory-related troubles remain in the game and once mentioning reconnections, my suspect would be to rather go and setup `.IMMEDIATE` + possibly let `ROUTER` benefit from explicit `PROBE_ROUTER` signalling.

Comment: I will check these out, thanks.  When you say to set .LINGER after initialization, do you mean set it to 0?

Comment: Absolutely yes :o)  for details kindly read thoroughly the ZeroMQ native core-API documentation. Worth one's time.